# Content in <Table> removes extra white spaces, unlike <div>

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have the same data being displayed in two different ways. One displays the information in a boostrap `<table class="table">`

```
 <td> @Html.Raw(Html.Encode(item.reply_content).Replace("\n", "<br />")) </td>
```

this displays the data as:

> 6W YT6

The other ways displays the information in a div

```
  <textarea name="Call_Desc" class="form-control" style="height: 300px; min-width: 91.5%; max-width: 91.5%; width: 91.5%;" id="comment" readonly>@Model.Call_Desc</textarea>
```

this displays the data as:

> 6W(3 white spaces)YT6

Is this a stylesheet issue, how can it be fixed?

Comment: As you regarded in the code sample, the contents in both cases are not the same. I believe that `@Html.Raw(Html.Encode(item.reply_content).Replace("\n", "<br />"))` may be printout different value than `@Model.Call_Desc`.

Comment: I agree they are not the same but I have used variations of these in divs and table tags and the common element here is that it only occurs in the table tags.

Comment: 1   2 `1   2` look at this comment

Comment: the first 1 2 has been written separated by three spaces, but it trimmed into one, while the second in the code displayed as it is.

Comment: In other words, apply the [**`white-space`**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) CSS property for your table cell.

Comment: Unfortunately applying white-space to the table css just ruins the entire table structure.